# Create Django Model from a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, django, model

I want to create a model from a list of dictionaries (i.e) it should be similar to this query

```
result = MyModal.objects.all()
```

I know that we can create an instance of a model like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects) `MyModal(**data_dict)`, I want something similar so i can pass in a list of dictionaries.

```
data_list = [{name: 'abc'}, {name: 'xyz'}]
# result = "Logic to create instance for 2 objects"
```

I want to serialize this data and then pass it to a REST API response.

Ping me in comments if more explanation is needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`bulk_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to perform multiple create in sigle query:

```
data_list = [{name: 'abc'}, {name: 'xyz'}]
obj_list = [MyModal(**data_dict) for data_dict in data_list]
objs = MyModal.objects.bulk_create(obj_list)
```

Comment: I want to pass it to a serialiser and then use that serialised data for a REST API, not going to create any new entries

Comment: @pavanskipo `bulk_create` return list of created objects and you can pass it to serializer. It should work I think.

Comment: Thanks alot, made slight modification to your code and it worked !!